# Playing youtube videos on android in qt C++ android application

Tags: android, c++, qt, video, youtube

I am working on Qt and C++ android application. i am able to play videos on my android phone from my own server on a remote PC using http request. But when i try to play a youtube video using http it did not play. if i put same URL in browser it plays. what might be the possible reason. I am not using java in my qt application.

Comment: The reason may be that youtube does not believe that this is user ( you do not send user agent etc, that usually is sent when you open URL in browser) and blocks you. You have two solution basically - continue to pretend to be user with a browser (via `setRawHeader` etc) or use youtube's API for this

Comment: @Shf How can i add setRawHeader, and what i need to set in Raw Header